# Loop and animate a div

Tags: javascript

```
// functie voor omlaag gaan van de lift en character
   function charliftdown1() {
            if (richting == -20){
                setInterval(liftdown, 500)
            }
   }
   function liftdown() {
           console.log(a = a - 2); // this one works
           positioncharacter.style.marginBottom = parseInt(positioncharacter.style.marginBottom)  -2 + "px";
   }
```

i tried it many ways but it still dont work. funny enough it work before?
what do i do wrong?

Comment: Can you create a demo to show your problem?

Comment: what error did it gave in console ?

Comment: http://athena.fhict.nl/users/i338168/DED/site/prototype.html

Comment: this is the link to my project. i want the red square go down in steps

Comment: on pageload: ReferenceError: browserName is not defined, on scrollwheel: TypeError: e is undefined

Comment: And what do i do now?

Comment: read all the comments above.. did you test for errors? Also the -5 rating means you might want to read about [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First fix your other issues.

Inside separate js file: `BrowserName` is not defined. Is it supposed to be a var or function? It you want to check the browser you can use `navigator.userAgent` and test for certain strings. Search this site for more info.

Scroll function: be careful with using function names. They may be reserved words. scroll is a word used by windows and by jquery.

Your onwheel and onkeydown seem to pass only 1 parameter into your function, so that's why your 2nd param is undefined. Why not do something like:

```
document.onwheel=doScroll;
document.onkeydown=doScroll;

function doScroll(e){
// e will contain the event
  if (e.keyCode == 38 || e.deltaY < 0 ) console.log("Up!");
}
```

After you fix these you handle other issues... maybe create a new post for it.